# Spring - inject JpaRepository in xml-config without using autowiring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently getting started on a project that uses spring-data in combination with JPA/Hibernate.
Right now, I'm injecting JpaRepositories using @Autowired annotations on the properties in question, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class EmployeeGenerator implements IDataGenerator {
...
    @Autowired
    private IEmployeeDao        dao;
...
}
```

.. where IEmployeeDao is an interface extending JpaRepository that is annotated as @Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface IEmployeeDao extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

     /**
     * Finds employees by username.
     *
     * @param username the username
     * @return the list of employees
     */
    List<Employee> findByUsername(String username);
```

Everything works fine using this approach - However, I'm rather used to doing most of my spring configuration work in XML because I personally like the idea of all relevant confguration being in the same place and visible at the first glance.

Now, as far as I understand JPA and spring-data, the repository instances are somehow created by the JPA entity manager, so I should be able to specify them as beans in the spring config xml using.. some kind of factory method?
I guess I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
<import resource="classpath:spring/db-context.xml"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="..."/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="..."/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
...
<bean id="employeeDaoImpl" class="IEmployeeDao">
     <factory-method="?????"> <!-- Is something like this possible??? -->
</bean>
```

After some reading I guess that autowiring the repositories is the "recommended" approach, and I do see some benefits doing it like that,
but still, out of interest, I'd like to get it working with pure-xml configuration (or at least without @Autowired, that is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the repositories using `<jpa:repositories />`. Then you can use the repository references in your XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />

</beans:beans>
```

> In this case we instruct Spring to scan com.acme.repositories and all its sub packages for interfaces extending Repository or one of its sub-interfaces. For each interface found it will register the persistence technology specific FactoryBean to create the according proxies that handle invocations of the query methods. Each of these beans will be registered under a bean name that is derived from the interface name, so an interface of UserRepository would be registered under userRepository. The base-package attribute allows the use of wildcards, so that you can have a pattern of scanned packages.

You can read more about it in the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.create-instances

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how to reference a repository from an xml bean, can you please explain?

Comment: @zaratustra I don't really understand your question. The repository declaration in the example above will give you the ability to autowire the repository in any of your spring beans (using XML configuration or annotations)

Comment: For example, consider `MyBeanController` is a bean declared in an `XML config`. The `XML` config does **not** contain the `<context:annotation-config/>` line. I create a new `Repository` bean called `MyBeanRepository` and I would like the `MyBeanController` to have a reference to the `MyBeanRepository` repository bean.
The common way is to use `@Autowire public MyBeanRepository repository;`, but since `annotation-config` is not enabled, spring will not inject the repository bean into the controller bean.
How can I inject `MyBeanRepostiory` using only `XML` configuration?

Comment: Have you read something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-injection or similar? You can basically declare `<property name="repository" ref="repositoryName" />` via property injection - this is equivalent to `@Autowire` on property.